# How to simulate a Velodyne sensor?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How would you simulate a velodyne sensor or any other 3d laser sensor?

I've tried to use the block laser plugin combined with a horizontal+vertical ray sensor but it looks like the vertical tag is bugged in the 1.9 branch of gazebo. At least, when I put more than 3 samples in the vertical block It takes forever to load on my i7 computer. (I attached parts of my sdf to the question)

I was wondering if anybody has been able to simulate such a 3d laser sensor.

```
<gazebo reference="laser_frame">
  <sensor name="velodyne" type="ray">
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>5</update_rate>
    <visualize>false</visualize>
    <ray>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>360</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-3.14159</min_angle>
          <max_angle>3.14159</max_angle>
        </horizontal>
        <vertical>
          <samples>3</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-0.43284</min_angle>
          <max_angle>0.03490</max_angle>
        </vertical>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.22</min>
        <max>50</max>
        <resolution>0.02</resolution>
      </range>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_block_laser.so">
      <frameName>laser_link</frameName>
      <topicName>scan</topicName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.02</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>5</updateRate>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

Thanks for sharing your solutions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5067/how-to-simulate-a-velodyne-sensor?/) by [fmder](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/469/fmder/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The vertical tag has [recently been fixed in the default branch of gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/798/fix-ray-sensor-vertical-ranges/diff), though it is probably still broken in 1.9.

An alternative approach for modeling the Velodyne is to mount a ray sensor on a spinning link, so that each scan occurs at a different time step as the laser spins.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-12-05**:
I guess that modeling the Velodyne as a spinning vertical 2D laser would be even more realistic than using block laser.

**Comment by [fmder](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/469/fmder/) on 2013-12-15**:
Thanks, that is what I did, I'll publish my code later this week for the spinning hokuyo.

**Comment by [lba5](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/982/lba5/) on 2014-10-12**:
Still have that code for the spinning hokuyo?

**Comment by [awesomebytes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/950/awesomebytes/) on 2015-03-09**:
Any code for the spinning hokuyo? Thanks.